How to get Solana Blockchain price data from an API endpoint?
I need to get Solana blockchain ticker data for prices.

you have a variety of options to chose from.
Here's my non-exhaustive list

coingecko API - https://www.coingecko.com/en/api
coinmarketcap API - https://coinmarketcap.com/api/
Binance spot API - https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md
Coinbase spot API - https://docs.cdp.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/api-prices/

Should you need a token specific to Solana

https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/price-api


Coded my tg bot in java and used this to do /price
        } else if ("/price".equals(messageText)) {
            String tokenPrice = fetchTokenPrice(tokenAddress);
            bot.execute(new SendMessage(update.message().chat().id(), tokenPrice));

private static String fetchTokenPrice(String tokenAddress) {
    HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("https")
            .host("public-api.birdeye.so")
            .addPathSegment("defi")
            .addPathSegment("price")
            .addQueryParameter("address", tokenAddress)
            .addQueryParameter("chainId", "101")  // replace with your correct chainId
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://public-api.birdeye.so/defi/price?include_liquidity=true&address=4bEMorkYYDojk98Pk2hRTScvh6HwKgvrikzEcP2dY545")
            .get()
            .addHeader("X-API-KEY", System.getenv("birdeyeapikey"))
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            return "Error: " + response;
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
        double price = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getDouble("value");  // Retrieve the price from the "value" field within the "data" object
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00000000000"); // adjust to desired precision
        return "The current price of $MINDN is: " + "$" + df.format(price) + " USD";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Exception when making request - " + e.getMessage();
    }
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for answering but usually you should add some text. Something like 'I used Birdeye, here's a link to their API docs' and then the code.
